# How to verify two different values from Jmeter response for the same key

Tags: jmeter

I'm calling GET API using HTTP request and getting JSON response like below,

> {"data":[{"id":"gYmSrePrAJHb8G0TDtsArEwvu","description":"Consultant Charge For MRI Scan","siteId":"HC0115B","episodeTypeId":null,"episodeType":null,"serviceCode":"C0000030","serviceCodeDescription":"Consultant Charge For MRI Scan","duration":30,"backgroundColour":"#788BFF","status":"I","includeInNewICESessions":false,"industryStandardCodeScheme":"ISC"},{"id":"Qcbg7JY83M96XJWDvPjtjZccq","description":"wqYhqXnDmU9cYc1JfZ5r","siteId":"HC0115B","episodeTypeId":"I","episodeType":"Inpatient","serviceCode":"P0006410","serviceCodeDescription":"Prosthesis, LENS SP-PC UV 24 DIOPTER (728A)","duration":26,"backgroundColour":"#E2FDFF","status":"A","includeInNewICESessions":false,"industryStandardCodeScheme":"ISC"}],"success":true,"errors":null,"statusCode":200}

If you observe status, some records we get I (Inactive) and A (Active) and both are valid and I should not get any other value rather than I/A.

I need to validate only status value from all the JSON response (there may be 100 or more records).

My validation is either I get A or I.. which response assertion should I use? OR how do I verify it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and the code like:

```
def statuses = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.status
statuses.removeAll(['I', 'A'])

if (statuses.size() > 0) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Unexpected statuses found: ' + statuses)
}
```

What it does is:

- Extracts all `status` attributes values into an [ArrayList](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html)
- Removes all occurrences of `I` and `A` from the list
- Checks list size, expected number of statuses is `0`, if it's higher - unexpected status is present somewhere in the response

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.. it working perfectly for me.